# C# sockets: do I need to reconnect every time or hold session?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client

My application is sending some big data (several Gb) every 10 seconds. I'm wondering if it is correct to call this code in send function?

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(...);
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    {
    }
}
```

Or do I need to create client and stream only once, and then hold id (so I have some kind of a session)?

Comment: If it was every 10s Id reuse the same one

Comment: @BugFinder Why? The overhead of making a new connection when you are sending several Gb is negligible.

Comment: because if you are repeatedly sending data, by the sounds of it, either it wont be available because you cant send Gbs in 10s, or if it is, you'll be closing it just to reopen it.. seems pointless

Comment: @BugFinder But keeping the connection inside the method allows you to encapsulate it nicely, storing a connection outside your send logic just seems like an annoyance.

Comment: this is why this is an opinion question not a technical one..there are reasons either way, it can depend if its a local or remote server, if its remote, your firewall admins usually like 1 long conneciton over lots of small - in fact 1 log can be configured to get more bandwidth the longer its open.. so, its all just options..